# Github actions Azure deployment python app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, github-actions

I would like to deploy an app function which will create a python function (function code is in the repo). I have a storage account error appearing.

[image: screenshot of actions error]

My repo: https://github.com/Palme240/GitHub-Ci-CD

Comment: In your function's configuration, do you have a setting called `AzureWebJobsStorage` with the value of the connection string to your storage account?

Answer (score 0):

> When request Azure resource at ValidateAzureResource, Get Function App
> Settings : AzureWebJobsStorage cannot be empty

According to the error message, you need to check whether the `AzureWebJobsStorage` property is empty in the app setting configuration.

The property `AzureWebJobsStorage` must be specified as an app setting in the site configuration.

The Azure Functions runtime uses the `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection string to create internal queues. When Application Insights is not enabled, the runtime uses the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` connection string to log to Azure Table storage and power the Monitor tab in the portal.

These properties are specified in the `appSettings` collection in the `siteConfig` object:

```
"appSettings": [
    {
        "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
    },
    {
        "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
    }
]
```

You can refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code#storage-account) for details.